# OS X 10.9 Change / reverse the default drag and drop mouse function from copy to move

Tags: copy, mouse, move, osx-mavericks

Anyone know how to change/reverse the default drag and drop mouse function from the default of copy to move **without using command or any other modifier keys** (truly one handed)?

I'm thinking that since I can count to 20 without taking off my shoe, I should be able move a file without touching my keyboard.

Comment: This question is connected to a larger ACL and permissions issue / question